# React on an app toggle switch chance in charms bar (allow position)

Tags: geolocation, winjs, windows-8.1

Is there a way to check a change in the app bar given by Microsoft? I like to react, if a user change the position settings for the geo location. 
I'm working with WinJs.[image]

Comment: "App bar given by microsoft" Are you talking about the settings you have created for your app? or the system settings..

Comment: I try to react to system settings.

Comment: I try to react to system settings in the charms bar, sorry.

Comment: I dont think it is possible to do that.Can you please let me know what is the need for it..

Comment: If an app is running and the uses switch off the position setting, I would like to react on this event. Now I've solved it with a check at every event with :
Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator() and getGeopositionAsync()